# What does the CSS specification say is correct way to measure an elements width?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, specifications

Chrome seems to measure an elements width from the inside of the margin including padding but Firefox and IE measure the boxes width where the border is (not including padding but inside margin). measuring the elements width from the border makes sense to me and is also helpful when coding because turning on borders will let you see the width of the element very easily but my question is what the CSS specification says is the correct way to measure the width of an element and if chrome is wrong or IE and Firefox are

thanks for your help

Comment: The way how you described the behaviour is confusing. Do you for instance know where exactly the padding and margin are? Also, are you aware about the box model bug in IE? Did you use the right doctype? Are you sure that FF behaves exactly the same as IE?

Comment: i had a div that was absolutely positioned so its bottom would be hidden at the top of the screen... the padding property was causing the div to hang down farther than the height but only in chrome... IE seemed like it was measuring the border as the height and not including padding... i wanted to know who was measuring correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The W3C CSS 2.1 Box Model Specification says that the width of an element does **not** include margin, border or padding.

In fact by specifying the CSS width or height properties you specify the space available to the content of a box (that is called *content area* in the specification) which does not include padding, margin or border.

Look at this example:

```
div { width: 100px; padding: 10px; margin: 20px; border: 2px; }
```

The distance between the vertical borders (including them) is width + padding-left + padding-right + border-right-width + border-left-width.
Margins are outside of the border-box.
The width (as intended by the CSS specifications) is instead 100px.

Internet Explorer renders web pages in *Standard Mode* or in *Quirks mode*.
If you want IE to behave as it should (so following CSS Standards) you have to force it to use the *Standard Mode* by using one of the DOCTYPEs reported in this article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/

This technique is called *doctype-switch*.

Firefox and the majority of other browsers follows the standard box model.

You can read the W3C box model specification here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#box-dimensions
But I suggest you to read a more easy-to-read (but really good) article like this: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/boxmodel

Another thing to say is that the CSS 3 specifications will include the [`box-sizing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing) property which will allow to specify for every element the way to interpret the `width` property (so if excluding or including padding and borders).
Anyway it will take years for the majority of browsers to implement the new (and not yet finished) CSS 3 specifications.

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to [read it](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).  Of course, every browser in the last decade implemented it differently.

The `width` property of an element is supposed to be the "content area width", and is not supposed to include margins, padding, or borders.  [IE did not implement it this way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) in certain versions and situations.  Generally other browsers follow the spec.

Answer (score 1):

All modern browsers render the box model properly. The responses here are long winded but correct. Essentially a block element with the following details:

```
border: 10px;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
width: 100px;
```

Would have the following characteristics:

1. The total space utilized by the element would be 160px wide. This is width+padding*2+margin*2+border*2 as we've specified symmetrical border, padding, and margin on both sides of the box.
2. The space available to the contents within the element is only 100px wide.
3. The space available up to the border of the element is 120px.

Chrome, Safari, FireFox, Opera, and IE6/7/8 should all display this behavior.